# Creating iOS App with database

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've searched web for an answer to this question but failed to find.

I want to create an app that already has data in it (data that doesn't needed to be downloaded from the web).

For example: an IOS navigation app that the pins are already in the map.

So, do I need to hard-code it into the app or is there a better way to do so?

Comment: You need to save which kind of data for your offline app?

Comment: you can seed the database, there are many tutorials out there.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Core Data in your application, It is very easy to work on and fast as well. 
Take a look at [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated). This is a really cool tutorial and will make understand things better.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, if the database is local, use Core Data please. Or if you so desired, you can manipulate sqlite directly.

If your database is remote, you may need to interface it with a web application, or port libraries (like mysql-connector/c or libpg) but that will be rather painful.

Shameless plug, I do have some tools up my sleeve (free & open source) that can help you write the web application without you learning another language.